# Google Load Balancer hosting two React apps on different paths

Tags: google-cloud-platform, url-rewriting, google-cloud-storage, load-balancing

I have two client-side rendered React app builds in two separate Google Storage buckets. I set up a Google Load balancer with two paths. The URL `example.com/app/a` points to one bucket and `example.com/b` points to the other.

If I open the `example.com/app/a` in the browser it shows the following:

```xml
 <Error>
     <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
     <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
 </Error>
```

If I click **Edit website configuration** on the bucket and add the `index.html` as 404 page, it works, but the browser shows a 404 error in the console.

Is there a better way to achieve this in 2022? When using nginx with rewrite paths and React routers' `basename`, it works. The corresponding nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
     listen       $PORT;
     server_name  localhost;
     root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     rewrite ^/app/a/(.*)$ /$1 last;

     location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
     }
}
```

How can this be achieved with Google's Load Balancer?

Comment: The bucket has to be public for this to work. You can edit the permissions on the bucket and set the users to allUsers. or follow the steps in this doc, especially this step https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#sharing

Comment: Do you use a loadbalancer? if so, can you share the configuration?

Comment: @boredabdel Thank you. This is exactly the guide I followed to set it up. The only difference is that I put two apps on different paths as outlined in the question.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I'm using the Google Cloud Load Balancer.

Comment: So, what's your load balancer configuration?

Comment: As pointed by @guillaumeblaquiere please provide your load balancer configuration so we can try to replicate your issue

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided, most probably the 'MainPageSuffix' and 'NotFoundPage' flags are not properly set for the backends, you can verify that with the command  `gsutil web get gs://<your-bucket-name>`, have to see an output similar to this one for each of your buckets:

```
{"mainPageSuffix": "index.html", "notFoundPage": "404.html"}
```

To properly set the flags use this command:

```
gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://<your-bucket-name>
```

Comment: @jz22 was this answer useful?